# Flex application works locally, fails when online (connecting to PHP script to insert row into DB)

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache-flex

I've got a Flex application that works wonderfully when I test it on my machine locally. It uploads files and send variables to a PHP script (that inserts them into a DB) with no errors when I run it locally. As soon as I put it online, the upload continues to work but something between my Flex application and the PHP script fails because no data is committed to the DB. I know the PHP script works fine - not only does it work when I run the Flex application locally but when I go directly to the PHP file online, a new empty line is added to the DB.

I initially thought that this was a cross domain issue so I added the following to the root of my hosted account:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
<allow-access-from domain="*.MYURL"/>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*.MYURL" headers="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

I based this off of what I found online which seems to have done nothing for me. I'd also be happy to provide an error message but I don't get one when I debug.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My first thought is a wrong URL...or maybe a firewall issue.  Try looking at the `Net` tab in Firebug when you run it from the online location.  Also, you can put your debug SWF online and connect to it using Flash Builder - see http://enterprisingflex.blogspot.com/2011/07/remote-debugging-in-flashbuilder.html for details.

Comment: My first thought would be differences in your amf_config.ini file.  Specifically the 'webroot' variable may be different in production box compared to the one utilized by development